# How to theme node delete page in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I just want to theme to node delete page in Drupal 7 . but it doesn't seems to working with template in new theme which is active now .I have made template page in theme and made code in template.php based on the form_id . The same thing I did for other forms like node create form for different different content types . But for delete a node this is not working . anyone knows the process to do this .

Comment: Alternatively, if you have to change a few elements, you could also use hook_form_alter() in a module. Though theming with that would not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that with "theme the delete page", you mean writing custom CSS rules that affect only the confirmation step page used to delete a node.

Then, you can do that with such a rule:

```
body.page-node-delete .theSelectorsYouNeed {
  color: red; /* ... + any rules you need */
}
```

Drupal 'injects' some context-depending CSS classes to the `body` tag of your template. For example: `.not-front`, `.not-logged-in`, ... and, what you need, `.page-node-delete`.

[Source](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7)